# Monogame - Changing background colour error

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I'm building a 2D platformer and I want to have different colour backgrounds for each level. I've made an object that when collided with, it places the character onto the next level by changing the `player.Position`, like so...

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime){

    if (player.Bounds.Intersects(teleportObj.Bounds))
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.SlateGray); // fails to change bg color
        player.Position = new Vector2(172, 0); // successfully changes character position
        MediaPlayer.Play(dungeonSong);  // successfully plays new song
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;  // successfully repeats new song
    }
}
```

I have already set a background for the first level to begin with in the Game1's `Draw()` function like this:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
```

But when my player collides with `teleportObj`, **the background color doesn't change.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.SlateGray);` is used in `Draw` function. Try creating new `Color` variable, and change that variable in `Update` method, and when using `GraphicsDevice.Clear(name of the variable);`, use it in Draw function.

Code for that would look like this:

```
Color backgroundColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{    
    if (player.Bounds.Intersects(teleportObj.Bounds))
    {
        backgroundColor = Color.SlateGray;
        player.Position = new Vector2(172, 0); 
        MediaPlayer.Play(dungeonSong);
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
    }
    else backgroundColor = Color.CornflowerBlue; 
}

protected override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{    
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(backgroundColor);
    *draw other stuff*
}
```